# List of Rootobject from JSON String

Tags: c#, json, xaml, data-binding

I get the JSON as only a rootobject.

```
 var parkinfo = new List<RootObjectUtrechtCity>();
        RootObjectUtrechtCity utrechtCityInfo = await ParkUtrechtCityProxy.GetUtrechtCity();
        parkStationsUtrechtCity.ItemsSource = parkinfo;
```

I want to put those guys in a list, and bind it to xaml. how to, code looks good, but binding is a problem.

the JSON is: https://stallingsnet.nl/api/1/parkingcount/utrecht

Thanx in advance, i'll credit you in my app.

Proxy

```
public class ParkUtrechtCityProxy
{
    public async static Task<RootObjectUtrechtCity> GetUtrechtCity()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("https://stallingsnet.nl/api/1/parkingcount/utrecht");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectUtrechtCity>(result);
        return data;
    }
}

public class RootObjectUtrechtCity
{
    public int totalPlaces { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int freePlaces { get; set; }
    public string facilityName { get; set; }
    public int occupiedPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="parkStationsUtrechtCity"
              Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RelativePanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="parkPlacesUtrecht"
                               Text="{Binding facilityName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="parkAvailableUtrecht"
                               Text="{Binding freePlaces}"
                               RelativePanel.Below="parkPlacesUtrecht"/>
                </RelativePanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly why the code you have written to deserialize that JSON is not working.  What have you tried so far, and how does it fail?  A [mcve] showing the classes you want to deserialize into, the code to deserialize into them, would be best.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON payload looks like this from C# POCO point of view:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int totalPlaces { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public int freePlaces { get; set; }
    public string facilityName { get; set; }
    public int occupiedPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

So if `ParkUtrechtCityProxy.GetUtrechtCity()` gets your json feed from the source and deserializes it properly, the code should looke like the following:

```
var parkinfo = new List<RootObjectUtrechtCity>();
parkinfo  = await ParkUtrechtCityProxy.GetUtrechtCity();
parkStationsUtrechtCity.ItemsSource = parkinfo;
```

#### Update

Update your proxy accordingly to make sure the JSON is serialized properly

```
    public async static Task<IEnumerable<RootObjectUtrechtCity>> GetUtrechtCity()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("https://stallingsnet.nl/api/1/parkingcount/utrecht");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObjectUtrechtCity>>(result);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm code does not do, get an error on parkinfo = await, maybe my proxy is wrong

Comment: Might be. Would it be okay to ask to see the gist of that proxy?

Comment: Updated my answer too. :)

Comment: hmmm.. VS2015 says cannot implicity... missing a cast. on the same parkinfo line in the await part.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake use List<> as return type instead of IEnumerable in your proxy.

Comment: Yup, found it. Thank you very much

Comment: Well next the binding.. :)

Comment: The binding looks alright. What kind of problem are you facing there.

Comment: That succeeded ;)